# How can I limit the resolution options in my display settings?

Tags: display, 19.04, display-resolution

Is there a way to restrict the resolution options that appear for my monitors - I often have to set them when I plug in to multiple monitors at work, which is kind of annoying, but fine.

What's driving me mad is that when I have to set them, there's around 30 different options, most of them in aspect ratios that will never ever make sense for my laptop screen.

Is there a setting somewhere that will let me cull the list down, to the 2-3 sensible choices I might actually want?

It's a System76 laptop, running 19.04, Gnome 3.32 and a Intel® HD Graphics 620, if any of that is relevant.

[image]